# How to solve the problem of each CSV element calculation error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file that must count and output the results.

The CSV file has millions of rows. The following is my CSV file screenshot.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_rows",1000000000)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",1000000000)
df = pd.read_csv("Ax_Seg_output_no_comma.csv")
cnted = df.groupby(['Content'],as_index=False)['Content'].agg({'cnt':'count'})
cnted.to_csv('01.csv',index=0)
```

I used pandas to count it, but I got some problems.

1. It has not to count properly.

   I need to get the result such as `A,5` `B,2` `C,1`......

   However, I got some wrong results is `A,5` `B` `C,1`

It has not counted some elements.

2. A part of the lines has not to count.
3. If I count only 25000 rows of the element, it can output the correct result.

The following is the wrong result:

[image]

And then, the normal result should be the following:

[image]

I doubt if it exceeds the pandas **limit**. I think it has no more errors.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

(It is the original CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18_Y3Wu8OFFpAzgRXRsNh8C_nyh8wPPEu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please explain what's the issue, exactly? What are you expecting to see that you're not seeing?

Comment: The issue is some elements have not to counted. I need to get the result such as ```A,5``` ```B,2``` ```C,1```...... However, I got some wrong results such as  ```A,5``` ```B``` ```C,1```. B has not counted by this program. I edited the question already. Thanks to remind me to explain more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the results are confusing as some of the items (the value of 'Content') is multi-line. That's why you're seeing things such as:

```
a

b:2
```

The reason that some items contain multi-lines / newline characters is that you have quote signs in your CSV. To ignore them, read the csv as follows:

```
import csv 
df = pd.read_csv("Ax_Seg_output_no_comma.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```